# Is it any way to test from vbscript if a folder is a symbolic link?

Tags: vbscript

I have some visual basic script code in my installer and i need to test that specific folder is a symbolic link or a normal folder. Is it any way to perform such task in vbscript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

File system items that are symbolic links have the [`FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332330.aspx) (1024) attribute set. You can check for this attribute like this:

```
Const FA_REPARSE_POINT = &h400

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fso.GetFolder("C:\MyFolder")

If (f.Attributes And FA_REPARSE_POINT) = FA_REPARSE_POINT Then
  ' The folder is a symbolic link
Else
  ' The folder is a normal folder
End If
```